# issue with paginated reading datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have a weired issue, I can't believe such a common feature could be broken (the error is certainely on my side), but I can't find how to make it work. I want to use the cursor from datastore to get paginated results, I keep getting all of them whatever i do

```
FetchOptions fetchOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.withChunkSize(5).prefetchSize(6);
String datastoreCursor = filter.getDatastoreCursor();
if (datastoreCursor != null) {
    fetchOptions = fetchOptions.startCursor(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(datastoreCursor));
}

QueryResultList<Entity> result = preparedQuery.asQueryResultList(fetchOptions);
ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();
// int count = 0;
for (Entity entity : result) {
    // if (++count == PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE)
    // break;
    Key key = entity.getKey();
    productList.add(populateProduct(key.getId(), true, entity));
}
toReturn.setDatastoreCursor(result.getCursor());
```

Also if I don't read the rows (uncomment the lines with `counter`) and get the cursor the resulting cursor is the same. I thought it might bring me back to the last read element under the datastabase cursor (thinking `result.getCursor()` reflects the state of the db cursor)

I'm getting a cursor with this value `E-ABAOsB8gEQbW9kaWZpY2F0aW9uRGF0ZfoBCQiIjsfAmKm_AuwBggIhagljaGF0YW1vamVyFAsSB1Byb2R1Y3QYgICAgICosgsMFA` that points to no more elements (I have 23 elements for my test that I all receive from the first query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a `QueryResultList`, the requested cursor will always point to the end of the list. As specified by the [javadoc of `QueryResultList#getCursor`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/QueryResultList#getCursor):

```
Gets a Cursor that points to the result immediately after the last one in this list.
```

Even though you provide a prefetch and chunk size, The entire result list will still have all of your results since you have not specified a limit. Thus, the expected cursor is the cursor after the final element.

If you only want a specific number of entities per page, you should set a limit on the `FetchOptions` using the [`limit` method](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/FetchOptions#limit%28int%29). Then when you call `getCursor()`, you'll get a cursor at the end of your page, as opposed to the end of your dataset.

Instead, you could also use a `QueryResultIterator`. Unlike the `QueryResultList`, calling `getCursor` on a `QueryResultIterator` will result in the cursor that points after the last entity retrieved by calling `.next()` ([javadoc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/QueryResultIterator)).

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer Patrick, I don't know why I looked at examples and forgot to look at the javadoc :)